# Draw string in Onpaint() block UI thread if string is too long

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have two UserControls which added in a form in my winforms project, one with the function to draw a string and make it scrolling from right to left and the other draw an other string and make it scroll from bottom to top over and over again controlled by calling Invalidate() inside a while(true) loop.But when one of my string become too long, about 1000 characters the UI Thread is blocked, so my questions are: What am I doing wrong? is there a better way to make text scrolling???
and bellow is my snippet of code:

```
 int scrollTextSpeed = 100;
 bool scrollingText = true;
 Thread updateUI ;

 void init(){
     updateUI = new Thread(updateScrollText);
     updateUI.Start();
 }

 void updateScrollText()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (scrollingText) {

              Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
              new MethodInvoker(Invalidate));
              Thread.Sleep(scrollTextSpeed);
            }
        }
    }


 protected override void OnPaint(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
    {

        SizeF stringSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(text, this.Font);

        var yPos = (this.ClientSize.Height / 2) - (stringSize.Height / 2);
        e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
        e.Graphics.DrawString(text, this.Font, brus,
        currentPos, yPos);
        if (fisttime)
        {
            currentPos = this.ClientSize.Width - 1;
            fisttime = false;
        }
        else
        {
            if (currentPos < (-1 * (stringSize.Width)))
                currentPos = this.ClientSize.Width - 1;
            else
                currentPos -= scrollPixelDistance;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do not invalidate in a busy loop. There is no point. Timers exist. There’s also no point in measuring the string every time if it doesn’t change. Nor to draw it every time since you could keep it as a bitmap

Comment: Why are you drawing the text? Why not use a `Label`?

Comment: I copy pasted your code into a new WinForms project, made it compile - it keeps scrolling with a string of 50000 characters, and the form still responds to user input.

Comment: Also, think about what happens to your `while (true)` loop if `scrollingText` becomes `false`... (Not that that is causing your problem, but it will cause other problems.)

Comment: @ Enigmativity: I tried to use label and move the label from right to left by set label.Left, it it's very lagging.

Comment: @ C.Evenhuis: let try with two of it

Comment: @user2905416 - And drawing it isn't lagging? Why is that do you reckon?

Comment: @user2905416 - Did you try using a WinForms Timer to move the `Label`?

Comment: @ Enigmativity: I did try, if I use two timer for two scrolling text it slow down the application.

Comment: @user2905416 Two threads that spam `Invalidate`, and two strings of 50000, still nothing is blocking the UI. I don't know if my code matches yours, though, but I'm afraid your code sample isn't enough to diagnose the problem.

Comment: @user2905416 - There's no way that a timer would slow down the app if it were used to animate a label. You must be doing something wrong. Can you post that code so that we can see?

Comment: Hard to guess how Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher ended up in a Winforms app.  It is not correct, it doesn't know beans about which thread is the correct UI thread.  Deadlock is certainly not unusual.  Use Control.BeginInvoke() instead.  You need a Form object, use Application.OpenForms[0] if you're desperate.  Do watch out for the scroll rate, if the UI thread can't keep up then it starts to burn 100% core and that looks like a "freeze" as well.

Comment: @HansPassant Good advice; it's already calling `Invalidate()` so already has the `Form` instance, but I still wonder what's causing a deadlock when all he's doing is `Invalidate()` every 100ms - except perhaps when calling `updateScrollText()` from the UI thread itself?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, I can't reproduce the issue that the UI thread is blocking. However I think you should refactor this part of the code, which will probably also solve the blocking UI problem.

Currently your scroll speed directly depends on whenever the UI thread decides to act on the `Invalidate()` requests. Furthermore you indicate that you will have more than one scrolling text, so configuring different scroll speeds for these texts will be nearly impossible.

With a bit of math you can determine the location of scrolling text at any given time, ie:

```
float x = ClientRectangle.Width - (((uint)Environment.TickCount / 40f) % 
        (stringSize.Width + ClientRectangle.Width));
```

Now that the scroll position no longer depends on the refresh rate, you won't need multiple timers. And with a simple `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` you wouldn't have to invoke anything from another thread.